# TestFlight cannot add additional testers

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

[image: Why can't I add new Testers?]

I have successfully added 3, but now when I go to add more, I see that I have 0 of 1,997 available. Is this a bug in Testflight?

When I enter info in the fields shown, the "add" button remains greyed out.

How do I add testers?

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add a build to the test group. Then, when I did that, I had to start entering email addresses and names. Once I did that, the numbers became more favorable.